# Decision tree question in R

Tags: decision-trees

After training and testing the decision tree model, it always gives me the same outcome on any given data. Im talking about a binary classification yes or no.
Basically when I do predict(fit_model, newdata=new_data) I always get no regardless the data I give. The model is quite simple and I can compute the outcome even by just looking at the tree. That's why if I give a certain combination of data, I would expect the outcome being yes by looking at the tree, but it still gives me no. Why that happens and how would I solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Do you have imbalanced data?

Comment: Decision trees are convenient for diagnosing what happens: take an example of a case supposed to be predicted as yes, and manually observe the decision tree conditions by visualizing the model. This should tell you what's going wrong: maybe the tree learns wrong conditions because it overfits, maybe it doesn't find the relevant conditions and defaults to the majority class, maybe it does represent the right answer and the issue is a bug when you apply it,...